# Looking for a way to Total each of my Invoices

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way to total my invoices in another column in SQL but struggling, does anyone have an idea on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT I.Invoice_ID AS "Invoice ID", I.Client_ID AS "Client ID",
       B.Client_Name AS "Clients Name", B.Client_Address AS "Clients Address",
       I.Invoice_Date AS "Date of Invoice", B.Course_ID AS "Course ID",
       C.Course_Description AS "Course Description", TO_CHAR(C.Cost, 'L9,999.99') AS "Cost",
       B.Attendees_No AS "Number of Attendees", TO_CHAR(C.cost * B.Attendees_No, 'L9,999.99') AS "Total"
FROM Invoice I, Booking B, Course C
WHERE B.Client_Name = 'Central Library' AND B.Course_ID = C.Course_ID;
```

[This is a picture of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4meF.png)

Comment: what do you mean by total my invoices?

Comment: I'm looking to have a grand total for each individual Invoice, in the example I included I have 2 invoices and the total of each booking is shown at the end. I'm sure it's possible to implement a ROLLUP function but struggling at how to implement it.

Comment: You really ought to consider switching to ANSI JOINs, rather than the old fashioned way to string tables together in the WHERE clause. How is Invoice related to booking or course in your query? Is it intentional that you only show the client details and address of a single client? What's your expected output?

Comment: The Client in this case makes a booking where the information on the booking such as number of attendees is contained. The Invoice is meant to contain all the bookings the client has made and each Client can have multiple invoices. No, there are more than 1 clients in the database. Course includes the course id, price and description. Is there a way to make it a bit more streamlined using JOIN conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path thinking about 'Rollup` In this case it's just a [window function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) that you probably need:

```
SUM(C.cost * B.Attendees_No) OVER (PARTITION BY I.Invoice_ID) as Total
```

This will spit out the sum of `C.cost * B.Attendees_No` for each `Invoice_ID`. So records in your record set with the same `invoice_id` should show the same `total` here.